# Check that a list of variables have each been set

Tags: javascript

I have an array filled with the names of variables like this:

```
var myVariables = [variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4];
```

Is there a simple way besides and `each` to test if all of these variables have been assigned a value (elsewhere in my code)?

Comment: Do you mean to check if none of them is `undefined`?

Comment: Currently you have an array with the **values** of these variables, not their names. This contradicts your description. What do you really have now?

Comment: @Kinduser Right

Comment: @FelixKling The variables are defined elsewhere (or not at all). Basically, assume I have a list of variable names and I want to check them to see if they are undefined.

Comment: `[variable1]` puts the **value** of `variable1` into the array, **not** its *name*. So if this is the code you actually have, then you simply have an array of values, not an array of variable names. Hence I'm asking you to clarify what you actually have.

Comment: *"The variables are defined elsewhere (or not at all)"* If a variable is not declared, then trying to reference it will throw a `ReferenceError`. I.e. `[variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4]` will throw an error if one of these variables is not declared. You'd have to test its existence *before* referencing it.

Comment: on a side note, how would I define an array of variable names?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), with that approach there is a chance you won't have to iterate the entire array:

```
const hasEmpty = myVariables.some(v => typeof v === 'undefined');
```

Comment: How can I use the output of this? Can I use `hasEmpty` in, say, an `if/then`? And is the value of hasEmpthy `true` or `false` only?

Comment: Correct, `hasEmpty` is a boolean value

Comment: And what's its scope? Can I use it anywhere in my script?

Comment: That depends on a lot of external factors - 'use strict', the context it is running (in a module, in a global scope script), how you define it (e.g. `window.hasEmpty...` vs. `let hasEmpty...`.). You can certainly make it available to any part of your script, or calculate/set it when and where you need it.

Comment: Short answer but it addresses well the matter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method :

> The some() method tests whether some element in the array passes the
>   test implemented by the provided function.

It could be more efficient than `forEach` method as it stops iterating (short circuit in a some way) as soon a element matches the condition.

For example to check that all elements are `> 0`, use `some()` with the reverse condition, that is : `<=0`.

```
var isFailed = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].some(x => x <= 0);
```

For example, here, as soon the first iteration, `some()` exits and return `false`.

Comment: Agreed on the approach, though I would say "It _could_ be more efficient", since it isn't guaranteed to be so.

Comment: Indeed. "could" or "should" are more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
return myVariables.indexOf(undefined) === -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If one of your variable is not defined, this will throw a `ReferenceError` such as mentionned in top comments by Felix Kling. Otherwise if it has the value `undefined` then you can check if your array contains `undefined` values.

## don't throw `Reference Error`

If you execute the code below you will get a `ReferenceError` since `variable1` has never been defined.

```js
const myArray = [variable1]
```

But this next code will just create an array with an undefined value in it, since the variable is declared:

```
let variable1
const myArray = [variable1]
```

## check if `undefined` is included

With ES 2016 [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
const isAllDefined = !myVariables.includes(undefined)
// use this boolean where you need it
```

Comment: is this faster than using indexOf? It's certainly less readable. EDIT: I suppose using includes is readable enough.

Comment: I didn't think about indexOf, and don't know about benchmark. For the readability, check the includes version :) I've even edited with only includes, best practice IMHO.

Comment: Is `isAllDefined` a boolean? What's its scope? Can I use it anywhere in my script?

Comment: Yes it is a boolean. For the scope this is a totally different question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/6320039.